# Free an array of struct

Tags: c, free

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

struct t {

    int value;
};

int main (void) {

    struct t *a = malloc(6*sizeof(struct t));
    struct t *b = malloc(sizeof(struct t));

    struct t *c = malloc(sizeof(struct t));
    c->value = 100;
    struct t *d = malloc(sizeof(struct t));
    d->value = 100;
    struct t *e = malloc(sizeof(struct t));
    e->value = 100;

    memcpy(b, a, sizeof(*a));

    int j = 0;

    while (j<6){
        a[j] = *c;
        j++;
    }


    int t = 0;
    while(t < 6){
        free(&a[t]);
        t++;
    }


    free(a);

}
```

I'm trying to free the elements inside the array one by one. But this code cannot run so I think there might something wrong with free inside the second while loop. After I changed the second while loop to:

```
    while(t < 6){
        printf("%d",a[t].value);
        t++;
    }
```

It will run. Any idea how can I free those elements? 
Thanks!

Comment: There is NO array involved anywhere. `a` is a pointer to a block of memory sufficiently sized to hold 6 `struct t`. (you can index `a` as you would an array to reach the separate structs) You simply `free(a);`, `free(b);`, `free(c);` `free(d);` and `free(e);`

Comment: But why I can print the value of those struct with index but can't free them with index?

Comment: What do you think one has to do with the other, @SadSalad?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to free the elements inside the array one by one. But this code cannot run so I think there might something wrong with free inside the second while loop.

Yes, what's wrong is the attempt to free the elements one by one.

You cannot free allocated memory in different divisions than it was allocated in.  The argument to `free()` must be a pointer value that was previously obtained from an allocation function (and not since freed).  The `free()` call will then free the entire block. It cannot see any subdivisions of that block that you may be using, and it would be unlikely to be able to honor them even if it could see them.

> Any idea how can I free those elements?

Free the whole block at once, after you're done with all the data within.  That is, just

```
free(a);
```

(And also, `free(b)`, `free(c)`, *etc*.)

Comment: Assuming you are running on a modern operating system, b c d and e will be freed as part of the program termination process after main completes.  Ps sorry John didnt recheck answers b4 hitting post

Comment: And so will `a`, @Abel, if it is not freed explcitly.  But as a model for how memory should be managed in a more complex program, which might not terminate immediately after it is done with the allocated memory, each allocated block should be freed when the program is done with it.

Comment: Agreed.  It appears a comment above mine was deleted where Sad asked what happens to the others if he only frees a.

Answer (score 1):

One free per malloc'd block.
When you malloc, you are not grabbing memory for each struct.  You are grabbing one block (per malloc call) that happens to be large enough to fit 6 structs for a and 1 struct each for the others.  You can only free each block of this block at once.  In this case you should be freeing a through e (which are addresses returned by malloc assuming you had enough memory).

You could if you really needed to, malloc an array of struct * then malloc blocks into those struct *, but why would you in this case where the struct is small and easily copied?

Answer (score 0):

The key is this: When you allocate a block of memory, `malloc` (`calloc` or `realloc`) will return a pointer to the beginning address in that block. You have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. `free()` must be passed the same address returned by `malloc()`.

You can not provide an address from the middle of the allocated block to `free()`. Why? Because that will not be an address originally returned by a previous call to `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. That is a requirement, see the man-page for `free()` ([man 3 malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html))

> ```
>    The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must have 
>    been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc(), or realloc().
> ```

So you can only make a call to `free()` providing a pointer holding an address that was previously allocated and returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. In your case that is `a`, not `&a[1] ... &a[5]`.